# Cannot override provider configuration error in installing DC/OS via Terraform on azure

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, dcos

Working on setting up DC/OS on Microsoft Azure using Terraform.
I'm using the [main.tf](https://docs.d2iq.com/mesosphere/dcos/2.2/installing/evaluation/universal-installer-0.3/azure/) provided in the official documentation. Every time I run *terraform init*
I get an error:

Error: Cannot override provider configuration
│
│   on .terraform/modules/dcos/main.tf line 138, in module "dcos-infrastructure":
│  138:     azurerm = azurerm

I have authenticated via **az CLI** specifically via the command
*az login --use-device-code*

My terraform version is:
Terraform v1.1.9
on linux_amd64

How can I resolve this?
my attempts to comment out the providers still produces this error.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using module in you `main.tf` file, You have to use **`Provider Aliases in main file**

**To declare multiple configuration names for a provider within a module, add the configuration_aliases argument:**

You can take reference of this aws and edit it for azure accordignly.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = ">= 2.7.0"
      configuration_aliases = [ aws.alternate ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Passing Providers Explicitly**

**main.tf**

```
provider "aws" {
  alias  = "usw2"
  region = "us-west-2"
}

# An example child module is instantiated with the alternate configuration,
# so any AWS resources it defines will use the us-west-2 region.
module "example" {
  source    = "./example"
  providers = {
    aws.alternate = aws.usw2
  }
}
```

You can refer this [***document***](https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/develop/providers) for information, How to use provider when using module in main.tf